# Wordpress rewritten URL structure

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, seo

My Wordpress site can be broken in two parts:

1. Content type as pages, having URLs like: `site.com/page/subpage/`
2. Content type as posts, having URLs like: `site.com/category/postname/`.

The URL `site.com/blog/` is a page having a "Blog posts" template. If I open one of the listed posts, I get redirected to `site.com/category/postname`, **but I'm interested to have `/blog/` in front of it**, like the following: `site.com/blog/category/postname`. Also, if I try to access a blog post without `/blog/` in front, I want to be redirected to the correct URL.

Another thing, the archive is of the form `site.com/01/2013/`, **but I would like to be like: `site.com/blog/archive/01/2013`**.

My question is: how can I rewrite the URLs so that I can those bolded above; to have `/blog/` in front of the `/category/` and `/blog/archive/` in front of `/01/2013/`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you show us the content of your `.htaccess` file so far?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set your settings described [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen).